# Making an adverb a topic for a sentence 無碍には

Tags: grammar, words

> 協力しよう、という提案を無碍{むげ}には断れなくなってしまうのだが

Can someone help me make sense of this?
協力しよう=let's cooperate
という提案を=This proposal
無碍には=Without any obstacle
断れなくなってしまう=End up becoming unable to refuse
の=Nominalizer
だ=copula
が=But

> Let's cooperate. Without any obstacle I ended up becoming unable to refuse this proposal, but...

I think this is how it should be translated, but I am still not sure.

Comment: Where did you get the definition "without any obstacle"?

Comment: I looked it up on my dictionary and It was written: 無碍=Free from obstacle. I looked up on my J-J dictionary and the definition was 何ものにも妨げられないこと。何の障害もないこと。また，そのさま。

Comment: 無碍に is a common 誤変換 of 無下に. https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%84%A1%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%AB-641220

Answer (score 1):

無碍にできない - その物事が重要なもので、いい加減に対処することができないさま (http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E7%84%A1%E7%A2%8D%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

So I think a better translation would be that it became difficult to decline, it's not such a trivial matter that it can be refused haphazardly.

Comment: なんと・・・Weblio辞書、漢字間違ってる・・・こっちは「無下」になってるのに・・http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%84%A1%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

Comment: 本当ですか。。 実用語子辞典で引いたら「差し障りがない」と書いてあったので、ここの文では相手に対しての差し障りですかね

Comment: う～ん。。。？「無下にできない」と「無碍にできない」の両方があって、意味が違う、ってことなんでしょうか・・・？明鏡には、「無碍」は「妨げがなく、自由自在であること」、「無下に」は「冷淡に。すげなく。そっけなく。」って書いてあります。なんだかよく分からなくなってしまいました。。。